# How to listen to orientation change event without actually changing the screen sizes?

Tags: android

I have an app that is written completely for portrait mode only.

But i have an activity where i am playing a video.

I want to detect that user has put the device in landscape position, so I will simply invoke an API call in the video player to set the video playback into full screen.

What I currently did was to add

```
    android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

In the android manifest, and then override this method to get the event callback in the code.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

However, i notice when I do this, my screen actually changes orientation.

Is there a way to stay in portrait mode, and only receive a callback from android?

Comment: please mark an answer as accepted if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the accelerometer sensor instead and detect when the phone is held in landscape orientation. That way, you can decide what orientation to show the screen in any situation.

To learn how to get the accelerometer data, see the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel).